# radmenu add click event to fire code behind code from code behind

Tags: vb.net, telerik

On my master page I have a telerek radmenu called "myMenu" than looks like this:

[image: Telerek Radmenu]

on my aspx page that uses the master page I am trying to alter the link on the button "door"
but the following wont work. Can you please help

```
Protected Sub Page_Load()

Dim H As RadMenu = DirectCast(myMenu.FindControl("House"), RadMenu)
Dim D As RadMenuItem = DirectCast(H.FindControl("door"), RadMenuItem)

D.click = LoadStuff()

End Sub


Private Sub LoadStuff()

'update something in vb.net

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options. First, I'll answer the question exactly as you asked. In this case, you need to use AddHandler which is similar to using the += in c# for assigning event handlers.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load()

    Dim H As RadMenu = DirectCast(myMenu.FindControl("House"), RadMenu)
    Dim D As RadMenuItem = DirectCast(H.FindControl("door"), RadMenuItem)

    AddHandler D.Click, AddressOf LoadStuff

End Sub


Private Sub LoadStuff(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    'update something in vb.net

End Sub
```

However, if you're not creating your menu in code, and it's already built at design time, why not just use the following:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load()

End Sub


Private Sub door_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles door.Click

    'update something in vb.net

End Sub
```